# Keras for find sentences similarities from pre-trained word2vec

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have pre-trained `word2vec` from `gensim`. And Using `gensim` for finding the similarities between `words` works as expected. But I am having problem in finding the similarities between two different sentences. Using of `cosine` `similarities` is not a good option for sentences and Its not giving good result. `Soft Cosine similarities` in `gensim` gives a little better results but still, it is also not looking good.

I found `WMDsimilarities` in `gensim`. This is a bit better than `softcosine` and `cosine`.

I am thinking if there is more option like using deep learning like `keras` and `tensorflow` to find the sentences similarities from pre-trained word2vec. I know the classification can be done using `word embbeding`  and this seems somewhat better options but then I need to find a training data and labeled it from the scratch.

So, I am wondering if there is any other option which can be used pre-trained `word2vec` in `keras` and get the sentences similarities. Is there way. I am open to any suggestions and advice.

Comment: have you checked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126539/using-pretrained-gensim-word2vec-embedding-in-keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before reimplementing the wheel I'd suggest to try [`doc2vec` method from gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html), it works quite well and it's easy to use.

To implement it in Keras reusing the embeddings you have computed with `gensim`:

1. Store the word embeddings in a file, one word per line with the corresponding embedding. Alternatively you can do as @Paul suggested and skip the step 2 and reuse the layer in step 3.
2. Load word embeddings into a Keras Embedding layer. You can checkout this [Keras tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings/) for more details (check how `embedding_layer` variable is initialized).
3. Then a sequence to sequence model can be used to compute the embedding of the text. In which you have an encoder that embeds the string and the decoder that converts the embedding back to a string. Here is a [Keras tutorial that translates from English to French](https://keras.io/examples/lstm_seq2seq/). You can use a similar process to transform your text into your text and pick the internal embedding for your similarity metric.

You can also have a look how the [paragraph to vector model](https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf) works, you can also implement it using Keras and loading the word embedding weights that you have computed.

Comment: @J.Ferranrons do you have any  links where I can check this internal embedding things that you have mentioned in step 3

Comment: @Ben in the link provided in section 3, you can look for the definition of the variable `encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]`. For a theoretical background, you can refer to this paper [Sequence to Sequence Learning with Neural Networks](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural-networks.pdf), in that paper the embedding is called `vector` or `fixed-dimensional vector`.