# How to Embed your Dataframe using already trained model with Gensim (GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk, gensim

I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.springboard.com/identifying-duplicate-questions-a-machine-learning-case-study-37117723844) in which i have a following Dataset from Quora:

[image]

Here i have already cleaned and tokenize the data in column **q1_clean** & **q1_clean**.

Now i have trained the **W2vModel** by using GoogleNews pretrained model with the following code.

```
# We are concating the two columns of Question1 and Question2

nData = pd.Series(pd.concat([data['q1_clean'], data['q2_clean']]))
model_w2v = Word2Vec(nData, size=300) 

# step 2: intersect the initialized word2vec model with the pre-trained fasttext model
model_w2v.intersect_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',lockf=1.0,binary=True)

# step 3: improve model with transfer-learning using the training data
model_w2v.train(nData, total_examples=model_w2v.corpus_count, epochs= 10)
```

Now i have to do the feature analysis, for that i have following function to get the average computed distance.

```
def get_pairwise_distance(word1, word2, weight1, weight2, method = 'euclidean'):
    if(word1.size==0 or word2.size==0):
        return np.nan
    dist_matrix = pairwise_distances(word1, word2, metric=method)
    return np.average(dist_matrix, weights=np.matmul(weight1.reshape(-1,1),weight2.reshape(-1,1).T))
```

Here i have computed the tfidf to use as a weights:

```
X_train_tokens = get_tokenized_questions(data=X_train)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
pass_through = lambda x:x
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=pass_through)
# compute tf-idf weights for the words in the training set questions
X_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train_tokens)

# split into two
# X1_tfidf -> tf-idf weights of first question in question pair and 
# X2_tfidf -> tf-idf weights of second question in question pair
X1_tfidf = X_tfidf[:len(X_train)]
X2_tfidf = X_tfidf[len(X_train):]
```

and i am calling this **get_pairwise_distance** function like in the [tutorial](https://medium.springboard.com/identifying-duplicate-questions-a-machine-learning-case-study-37117723844).

```
#cosine similarities
# here X1 and X2 are the embedded versions of the first and second questions in the question-pair data
# and X1_tfidf and X2_tfidf are the tf-idf weights of the first and second questions in the question-pair data

cosine = compute_pairwise_dist(X1, X2, X1_tfidf, X2_tfidf)
```

**For this function i need to pass the embedded version of *q1_clean* and *q2_clean* as X1 and X2 where weights are already computed using TFIDF. and i am getting no clue how to embed these two columns into vectors using pretrained model and pass it to the given function?**

Comment: Tokenize your data, substitute your tokens with embeddings, compute embedding for your feature by either averaging your embeddings or weighting them with tfidf, find cosine similarity.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I have added the description again, i am already computing the tfidf to use them as a weight while getting average. but what will be the value of X1 and X2, to pass. because we need to convert q1_clean and q2_clean as X1 and X2 in the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using-pretrained-gensim-word2vec-embedding-in-keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126539/using-pretrained-gensim-word2vec-embedding-in-keras)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Keras Embedded Matrix`. Follow the link below.
 [Keras Embedded Layers](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/)