# How to know that the token ids in a gensim pre-trained word2vec will match the ids of a tokenizer's vocabulary

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gensim, embedding

I am building a pytorch BiLSTM that utilizes pre-trained gensim word2vec. I first used a `nn.Embedding` layer that was trained with the model from scratch but, i decided to use a pre-trained word2vec embeddings to improve accuracy.
My model architecture follows a simple BiLSTM architecture, where the first layer is the embedding layer followed by a BiLSTM layer(s), and lastly two feed forward layers.

```py
import torch
import gensim

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

word2vec = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('path_to_word2vec/wikipedia_cbow_100')
weights = torch.FloatTensor(word2vec.wv.vectors)

class BiLSTM_model(torch.nn.Module) :
    def __init__(self, max_features, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, lstm_dropout) :
        # max_features is the vocabulary size (num of tokens/words).
        super().__init__()
        # self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(max_features, embedding_dim, padding_idx=0)
        self.embeddings = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(weights)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(word2vec.wv.vector_size,
                            hidden_dim,
                            batch_first=True,
                            bidirectional=True,
                            num_layers = num_layers,
                            dropout=lstm_dropout)
        self.relu=nn.ReLU()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim * 2, 64)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, config['num_classes'])

    def forward(self, input):
        embeddings_out = self.embeddings(input)
        lstm_out, (hidden, cell) = self.lstm(embeddings_out)
        hidden = torch.cat((hidden[-2,:,:], hidden[-1,:,:]), dim = 1)
        rel = self.relu(hidden)
        dense1 = self.fc1(rel)
        drop = self.dropout(dense1)
        final_out = self.fc2(drop)

        return final_out
```

i use a `keras` tokenizer to tokenize the text and obtain the token ids.

```py
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

## Tokenize the sentences
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=config['max_features'])
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(train_X))
train_X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_X)
test_X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_X)
```

finally i use a standard training loop with an optimizer and a loss function. The code runs fine but there are no performance gains from using the pre-trained embeddings.

I suspect that it has to do with token ids not matching between the `keras.preprocessing.text` tokenizer and the `gensim` pre-trained embeddings for the words. My question is, how do i confirm (or deny) this inconsistency and ,if it is the case, how do i handle the issue?

Note: i am using a custom word2vec embeddings for the Arabic language. You can find the embeddings [here](https://github.com/bakrianoo/aravec).

Comment: This already has a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57375054/10475762

Answer (score 0):

After looking into *jhso*'s comment. It seems that the solution for this problem is to use `word2vec.wv.index2word` which will return the vocabulary (words) as a list sorted in an order which reflects a word's embedding.
for example, the following code:

```py
pretrained_embedding = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('path/to/embedding')
word_vectors= pretrained_embedding.wv
for i in range (0,3):
  print(f"{i}: '{word_vectors.index2word[i]}'")
```

will print:

```py
0: 'this'
1: 'is'
2: 'an'
3: 'example'
```

where `this` token will have the id `0` and so on.

You then use `word2vec.wv.index2word` as input to the `keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` object's `.fit_on_texts()` method as following:

```py
vocabulary = pretrained_embeddings.index2word
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=config['max_features'])
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(vocabulary)
```

this should preserve the token ids between the gensim word2vec model and the keras tokenizer.

Comment: The `.index2word` property no longer exists in recent Gensim (v4.0+, since March 2021). The `.index_to_key` property has replaced it, & contains a list of all known words, in the same order as their vetors appear in rows in raw backing `.vectors` `numpy`-array. Similarly, the `.key_to_index` property is a `dict` offering lookup of row index from a word. A Gensim contribution that could create a standard Keras `Tokenizer` from `KeyedVectors` would be valuable. Tricky aspets to reconcile might be matching Keras practice of reserving the 0-slot for no-word, & an optional entry for an `oov_token`.